# How to add script files using headScript with Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, layout, head

I am developing a new zend framework application, and when I just hard coded the headScript section for my layout.phtml file and Bootstrap _initScript method, when looking at the source-code after not having the script loaded... a got a really weird result.

I got this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
    /js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js    //-->
```

Here is my layout.phtml code:

```
<?php echo $this->doctype(); ?> 
<html>
    <head>
        <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Here is my Bootstrap.php code:

```
protected function _initScript()
{
    $this->view->headScript()
       ->prependScript( "/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" );
}
```

As you can see it is very ordinary code!

Anybody could help me find out what's going on here?

Comment: With an interactive debugger you can find it out easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to add "file" not "script".

Change Bootstrap.php to:

```
protected function _initScript()
{
    $this->view->headScript()
       ->prependFile( "/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js", $type = 'text/javascript' );
}
```

Also check this for [headScript reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript).

Any questions? :)

Comment: Same result without `$type = 'text/javascript'`.

Comment: Don't bury me alive if I follow semantics :D Yes, +1 to your comment, it is not mandatory but, zend semantics (coding , conventions and stuff) requires me to write it. However, during RAPID development it is OK to miss on that part!

Answer (score 3):

I find that when setting up the view it's usually better to get the view object, set the placeholder values and then return the view, something like:

```
protected function _initView()
    {
        //Initialize view
        $view = new Zend_View();  

        //set doctype for default layout
        $view->doctype(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->view->doctype);

        //set css includes
        $view->headLink()->setStylesheet('/css/normalize.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/blueprint/src/liquid.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/blueprint/src/typography.css');

        //add javascript files
        $view->headScript()->setFile('/javascript/modernizr.js');
        $view->headScript()->appendFile('/javascript/jquery.js');

        //add it to the view renderer
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                'ViewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);

        //Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
        return $view;
    }
```

I'm not sure how well the `$this->view->` syntax works from the bootstrap but I suspect it has some issues.

Comment: +1 for putting out the logic But, as we can see in the question, he has displayed the HTML source output!

Comment: I've created a method for handling my view this way: $this->view = Zend_Layout::startMvc()->getView(); That's how I am getting the view inside the Bootstrap across the methods...

Comment: Thanks for educating. *Plans out a prank for his colleagues*

Answer (score 0):

I use the Zendx_jQuery component (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zendx.jquery.html), I find it handy, especially if you use jQuery UI in your forms.

In Bootstrap.php :

```
protected function _initjQuery()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_');
    return $view;
}
```

In my layout html header :

```
$this->jQuery()->setLocalPath($this->baseUrl('js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'))
        ->setUiLocalPath($this->baseUrl('js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js'))
        ->addStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css'))
        ->enable()
        ->uiEnable();

/* I only print jquery css in the header */
<?= $this->jQuery()->setRenderMode(ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_STYLESHEETS); ?>
```

In my layout body bottom :

```
<?= $this->jQuery()->setRenderMode(ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_LIBRARY | ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_SOURCES | ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_JAVASCRIPT | ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_JQUERY_ON_LOAD); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$this->headTitle('Your title');
$this->headScript()->headScript()->prependFile('/js/jquery.js');
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/yourcss.css');

echo $this->doctype();
?>

<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</body>
```